# TypeError: Cannot set property 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am new in typescript, I made this piece of code to test a method with jest,

```
describe('book', () => {

    let hostelClient: HostelClient;


    it('should book', async () => {

        hostelClient.getRequestByIdAsync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({});

        // Assert
        let exceptionThrown = false;
        expect(exceptionThrown).toBe(false);
     });

});
```

but I have this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property 'getRequestByIdAsync' of undefined
```

and

```
@Service()
export class HostelClient  {

    constructor() {
        throw new Error('not allowed);
    }
..
}
```

Comment: Should it not be let hostelClient = new HostelClient; - I don't think your instantiating your hostelClient variable correctly

Comment: `let hostelClient: HostelClient` - this just defines a variable `hostelClient` of type `HostelClient`. But you never store an actual instance of `HostelClient` in it -> `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
describe('book', () => {

let hostelClient: HostelClient = new HostelClient();


it('should book', async () => {

    hostelClient.getRequestByIdAsync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({});

    // Assert
    let exceptionThrown = false;
    expect(exceptionThrown).toBe(false);
 });
});
```

In your example, you are **defining** the variable but you aren't instantiating the variable as a new hostelClient.